# Should we hire ex-Google engineer or equally good regular candidate?

Tags: job-offer, human-resources

I'm facing a tough dilemma, we're down to two candidates whom are both equally talented. One wants to move from Google to our company because he is really interested in the business domain. The other one appears to come from a struggling background, he appears eager to take the opportunity to make something out of himself.

The senior management is of course much more interested in candidate from Google. This makes sense in many ways.

However I know that for this particular position, both would be more or less equally good. I can't shake off the feeling that candidate from Google can likely get a job any day, anywhere. The other candidate appears to be struggling and this position could change his life prospects.

When faced with two candidates who are both fit for the available position, can we take in to consideration the impact the job offer will have on their lives. Will giving the vacant position to the candidate who needs it more, be beneficial for the company in the long run?

Comment: I think many people who are responsible of hiring someone in the IT wish they had the tough dilemma of having to choose one capable IT guy over the other.

Comment: Well, if both are capable, which one is the best cultural fit? If you don't know, you need more/better interviews.

Comment: Maybe you can edit the question to remove Google and say "a famous company"? Also, your question title doesn't hint on your actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is my personal opinion, as I don't think this question has an objective answer.*

I think you need to look at what's best for the workplace and your company here as that's what senior management will want you to do.

**The Google Employee** - He'll probably be a great asset to the company and increase prestige for the business. Being able to put on the website "ex-google employees" looks rather nice.

However, he might move on to something bigger and better later on, especially if he just left Google because your project looks interesting.

**The Other Candidate** - If he's from a struggling background this could be an asset to you, he's not likely to leave and will (in all likelihood) work harder for the company because of the opportunity he's been given.

He may turn out to be more dedicated than the guy who came from Google in the long-run as he's yet to prove himself.

---

Personally, I'd pick **'The Other Candidate'** for those reasons, he'll probably be a better long-term investment but you're taking a faily large gamble there.

Having been **'The Other Candidate'** several times now, it makes me more dedicated when people are willing to give me a shot.